# difficulties installing pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, installation

he folks, I've been trying to to install pymssql and I get the following error

```
    Collecting pymssql
  Using cached pymssql-2.1.1.tar.gz
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('CentOS', '6.6', 'Final')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    Installed /tmp/pip-build-xdzeoR/pymssql/setuptools_git-1.1-py2.6.egg
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('CentOS', '6.6', 'Final')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    building '_mssql' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
    _mssql.c:314:22: error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from _mssql.c:316:
    cpp_helpers.h:34:19: error: sybdb.h: No such file or directory
    _mssql.c:532: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘BYTE’
    _mssql.c:683: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘DBPROCESS’
    _mssql.c:722: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘DBPROCESS’
    _mssql.c:775: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘BYTE’
    _mssql.c:776: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘BYTE’
    _mssql.c:1027: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
    _mssql.c:1031: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__Pyx_PyInt_from_py_DBINT’
    _mssql.c:1209: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:1210: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:1211: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:1212: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:1214: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_f_6_mssql_db_cancel’
    _mssql.c:1215: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘struct’
    _mssql.c:1216: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘struct’
    _mssql.c:1226: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:1227: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:1228: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:2705: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:3097: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:3570: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    _mssql.c:3669: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

The error is even longer.....Anyway, I've found other SO questions relating this, and I've checked (and installed if missing) python-dev, freetds-dev, Cython.... Can you guys see what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

For me, on red hat 6, the problem was that the setup was looking for the headers files in the wrong directory. Creating a symlink to this directory and then re-install pymssql resolved the issue:

```
ln -s /usr/include/freetds/ /usr/local/freetds
```

I hope this will help

Comment: I have the same issue. However, the above solution didn't work for me.